# How to append javascript content in html

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, append

i already worked in ajax and append content is not working my html field like

```
<div class="input-field hidemodals">
      <select class="model_select"   onchange="showfunction()"  id="modal_number">
              <option value="" disabled selected> Select Model</option>
      </select>
</div>
```

in javascript i will do

```
$.ajax({
    url:"https://api.wheel-size.com/***/***/",
    method: 'GET',
    data: {user_key: '*************', make:valueSelectedmakes , year:select_year },
    dataType:"json",
    cache: false,
    success: function(datases) {
var obj = JSON.stringify(datases); 
        if(datases){
                var len = datases.length;
                var txt = "";
                  if(len > 0){
            for(var i=0;i<len;i++){
                        if(datases[i].name){
                             $('#modal_number').append("<option value="+datases[i].slug+">"+datases[i].name+"</option>");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }    
         }
});
```

i will console append data that show in console ,but the result not showing in html part ,why?

Comment: Are you getting an error in the console?

Comment: I'd expect that to work. (It's not how I'd do it, not least because you want to defend against HTML chars in `datases[i].name`, but I'd expect it to work.) Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/)). You can use `setTimeout` to emulate the ajax call.

Comment: @evolutionxbox no error showing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your code with dummy data and it's working fine.
Do you get the response in below format?

```
var data = [{name:"test", slug:"test"}, {name:"test1", slug: "test1"}]
```

Can you please post the snapshot of response that you getting in datases object? Alternatively Try below code and check if it works.

```
$.ajax({
    url:"https://api.wheel-size.com/***/***/",
    method: 'GET',
    data: {user_key: '*************', make:valueSelectedmakes , year:select_year },
    dataType:"json",
    cache: false,
    success: function(datases) {
var obj = JSON.stringify(datases); 
        if(datases){
                var data = [{name:"test", slug:"test"}, {name:"test1", slug: "test1"}]
                var len = data.length;

                  if(len > 0){
            for(var i=0;i<len;i++){
                        if(data[i].name){
                   var modalElement = document.getElementById("modal_number");
   var option = document.createElement("option");
 option.text = data[i].name;
 option.value = data[i].slug;
  modalElement.add(option);


                        }
                    }
                }
            }    
         }
});
```

Comment: console.log(datases; i get result like   (15) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {slug: "1-series", name: "1 Series", name_en: "1 Series"}
1: {slug: "3-series", name: "3 Series", name_en: "3 Series"}
2: {slug: "5-series", name: "5 Series", name_en: "5 Series"}.....14: {slug: "z4", name: "Z4", name_en: "Z4"}
length: 15
__proto__: Array(0).

Comment: It seems no issue with response too...did you try above code?

Comment: Just to make sure it's not issue with response, can you try with dummy data that I have used above. Keep your all code as is, just inside success use dummy object data. And append same to the drop-down. Fourntunately if it works then we will rectify your original response and make it work.

Comment: I have modified my answer just run it for test with dummy data

Comment: i try with dummy data no changes and no error ,you see  my html content there is three select box this one is last

Comment: Ohk...which browser you trying with. Try with different browser than you trying now.

Comment: yes i try chome and firefoxe and brave no change ,i just call a function and append some data to that area that not working